# Display a number in a paragraph element multiple times from a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display a number from a JavaScript function multiple times (from a loop) in a paragraph element with ID="demo" in the html.

My browser's webpage freezes when running the program.

What is the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
  function func(x)
  {
     for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
       document.getElementbyId("demo").innerHTML=(x*i)+"</br>";
  }
</script>
<body>
  <form>
    input year:
    <input type="text" id="year">
    <input type="button" value="find type" onclick="func(year.value);">
   </form>
   <p id="demo"></p>

 </body>
```

Comment: why is input year not in a label

Comment: i think it does not change the problem

Comment: You have a typo in the JS, you have `getElementbyId`, instead of `getElementById`, but this shouldn't freeze the browser, the problem must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why your browser's freezing -- possibly you're seeing no results because of the typo in `getElementbyId` (should be `getElementById`)?

A secondary issue: every pass through your `for` loop is overwriting the previous ones, so you'll only see the results from the final iteration.

Instead, append the HTML on each pass through the loop, or collect it in a variable and drop it into the document at the end, as I've done here:

```js
function func(x) {
  var ret = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ret += (x * i) + "<br>"; // </br> is not correct; <br/> is not necessary
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ret;
}
```

```html
<form>
  input year:
  <input type="text" id="year">
  <input type="button" value="find type" onclick="func(year.value);">
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>
```